# Qt - overlap labels in QVBoxLayout

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to make labels overlap each other in `QVBoxLayout` like this:

```
this->layout = new QGridLayout;
this->layout->addLayout(new QVBoxLayout, 1, 0);

for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
    ClickableLabel *label = new ClickableLabel();

    auto stack = this->layout->findChildren<QVBoxLayout*>();
    stack[0]->addWidget(label);
    stack[0]->setAlignment(Qt::AlignTop);

    button->setGeometry(10000, 100, 0, 0);
}
```

Now the `setGeometry` is doing nothing. So my question is: Can I achieve overlaping labels in `QVBoxLayout`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't achieve overlaping labels in `QVBoxLayout`.

Comment: Is there some layout in which I can do that? besides gridLayout(I tried it, its possible but there was problem with maximum window size or something)

Comment: No - the purpose of layouts is (besides other things) to not allow overlapping - layouts lay out controls in some nice manner.

Comment: So can you give me advice about some free space where I can position labels in my main QWidget?

Comment: Simply don't use layouts - lay out your controls manually. But it has serious drawbacks (e. g. in the case of resizing the window - if you don't respond in this event in your code, controls will be frozen in their place and may be invisible in the case they are out of the (small) window).

Comment: But how can I not place it in layout? Because my main widget is QWidget and when I type `this->...` there is nothing like `addWidget`

Comment: You have to first create a control (as you did) and then use `setGeometry()` method for it (as you did with `button` in your code, but not with zeroes for width and hight). Completely omit commands which create and add a layout.

Comment: This is not nice solution, It wont show until I tell it to `->show()` and the label is not part of a QWidget. I am making a card game and I need to make cards overlap somehow like in Solitaire.

Comment: So you need something else - *drawing*. Use `QPainter` class as the base class - there are many examples bundled with Qt.